# How to mark a component selector as deprecated?

Tags: angular, selector, deprecated

I have a component

```
@Component({
  // todo the app-old-selector selector must be removed in the next version
  selector: 'app-new-selector,app-old-selector',
  templateUrl: './component.html'
})
export class Component {
}
```

What is the best way to inform a developer that `app-old-selector` is deprecated?

Comment: I know its too late but I have written a re-usable decorator which serves the purpose. Please go through my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably you can write something like this inside your component code:

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
 selector: 'app-new-selector,app-old-selector',
 templateUrl: './component.html'
})
export class YourComponent {
    constructor(elem: ElementRef) {
        const tagName = elem.nativeElement.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (tagName === 'app-old-selector') {
           console.warn('message');
        }
    }
}
```

It means that we simply compare the tag name of currently started component with the string representing deprecated value. If they are equal - it means that you now need to inform developer.

Here is a working [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-examples-oducty). Feel free to run it with console opened.

Comment: What about a static checking?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I would like to help developers during code writing as Typescript does it :)

Comment: Probably you could try to pay with @deprecated attribute of JSDoc. 
http://usejsdoc.org/tags-deprecated.html

Answer (score 8):

I have written a reusable decorator which marks components' selectors as deprecated.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

export function Deprecated(oldSelector: string) { // This is a decorator factory
  return <T extends Constructor>(Base: T) => {
    return class Deprecated extends Base {
      selectors = [];
      constructor(...args: any[]) {
         super(...args);
         const selector = new Component((Deprecated as any).__annotations__[0]).selector;
         this.selectors = selector.split(', ');
         this.selectors = this.selectors.filter(selector => selector !== oldSelector);
         console.warn('The selector "' + oldSelector + '" is going to be deprecated. Please use one of these selectors [ ' + this.selectors.toString() + ' ]');
      }
    };
  };
}
```

Now we just have to decorate our component class with this decorator function with parameter like below

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-old-app, my-app-new',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
@Deprecated("my-old-app")
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

Please find the code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/deprecated-custom-decorator) at stackblitz.

Also, please read my [blog](https://medium.com/@dileepkumarjami/how-to-mark-an-angular-components-selector-as-deprecated-aad11bb9feda) on the same topic which has the explanation on the logic.

Comment: The idea behind this is really powerful. However, it does not work with Angular v15+ any longer! I've taken your idea and elaborated on this a bit. However, to me it is not clear how to construct the new Class to obtain the selectors, or use Reflect to do this, other than how I did it in this example: https://angular-deprecated-decorator-jgolrf.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 5):

Also, you can simply use [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/)'s @deprecated instead, like so:

```
/**
* @deprecated write further comments here
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'component-name',
  templateUrl: './component-name.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-name.component.scss']
})
```

Comment: This deprecates the class, but does not have any effect on the selector. So you probably would never notice the deprecation

Answer (score 3):

With version 2023.1.3 of [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/), the IDE will now use strike-through styling for usage of a deprecated component.

```
/**
 * @deprecated DO NOT USE THIS TABLE.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-old',
  templateUrl: './old-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./old-table.component.scss']
})
```

Now inside another component template, where we use the deprecated component, the IDE will display as follows:
[image: usage of a depcrated component in an angular template]

**Note**: this only seems to work when the JSDoc comment is placed *above* the `@Component` annotation. If you put it below it (and directly above the `export class OldTableComponent` declaration), the strike-through styling will not be applied

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there is no built-in way to do this.  However, you could try to alert a developer using the `ElementRef` feature:

```js
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-selector,app-old-selector',
  templateUrl: './component.html'
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(elem: ElementRef) {
    if (elem.nativeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'app-old-selector') {
      console.warn(`'app-old-selector' selector is deprecated; use 'app-new-selector' instead.`);
    }
  }
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you need this feature to be reusable and want to ensure consistency across your library, you could make an injectable service, like this:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Deprecator {
  warnDeprecatedSelector(elem: ElementRef, oldSelector: string, newSelector: string) {
    if (elem.nativeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === oldSelector) {
      console.warn(`'${oldSelector}' selector is deprecated; use '${newSelector}' instead.`);
    }
  }
}
```

```js
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-selector,app-old-selector',
  templateUrl: './component.html'
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(elem: ElementRef, deprecator: Deprecator) {
    deprecator.warnDeprecatedSelector(elem, 'app-old-selector', 'app-new-selector');
  }
}
```

Comment: but this not reusable way no I need to copy this code every way 

Comment: You could make this into an injectable service if you needed it to be reusable.

Answer (score 2):

#### Angular 14.1+ Decorator:

```
import { reflectComponentType } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Deprecation decorator
 */
export function Deprecated(newSelector: string): ClassDecorator {
   return (target: any) => {
      const metadata = reflectComponentType(target);
      const selector = metadata.selector;
      console.error(`❌ The selector <${selector}> is deprecated. Use <${newSelector}> instead.`);
   }
}
```

Can be used as:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'ui-preview-image',
})
@Deprecated('ui-new-preview')
export class PreviewImageComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
```